# How to find element iframe by attribute src containing specific text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

What is a best way to find element **iframe** by attribute **src** containing text **about** . this is HTML code

```
<iframe id="fancybox-frame1464160624818" 
    name="fancybox-frame1464160624818" 
    class="fancybox-iframe" 
    allowfullscreen="" 
    scrolling="auto" 
    src="About.jsp?fancyBox=true">
</iframe>
```

Locating by ID, name, class name is not relevant.

I can find ALL iframes in page by tag name iframe and then check their src attribute by get_attribute method but i would like to find iframe by unique src attribute.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You know what beautiful? soup is beautiful: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: What is soup is beautiful?

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath.  I believe the expression is something like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'About'])]")
```